# How to search by image from the iPad?

Tags: ipad, google-apps

Google only allows image search from the camera directly (and not the gallery), but doesn't allow iPad users to search by uploading an existing image or typing a specific URL.

How can I search by image from an iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're on the Google Images page scroll all the way to the bottom. There is a choice there to use either Google Tablet or Classic (defaults to tablet on the iPad). Click on classic and you should get the same options as on your mac/pc.

[image]

Comment: I tried this with my iphone (classic Google on Safari), but the camera icon still doesn't appear. Maybe that will be next.

Comment: Since Google added "infinite scrolling", it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What if you did a "Request Desktop Site" instead?

Comment: In 2020, this is no longer a solution as they appear to have removed that option (or I'm just not able to find it)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind installing and using [Google Chrome browser](https://appsto.re/nl/NVp8F.i), you can tap-hold on any image and the "search google for this image" link is right there. Imho the easiest option.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an app-free way to perform Google Image search on Safari (ios devices)

1. Tap and hold on the picture you want to search and choose Copy to take its link.
2. Go to google.com, choose tab Image and paste the link into the search box and enter.
3. You will see the text **For matching images, try search by image** right under the menu bar . Tap on "search by image" and here we go!

[image]

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Reverse image search is especially helpful for determining the original author 
of the image and, for the photographer, seeing if any of his or her photos were 
used without permission. For mobile and desktop you can use https://searchbyimages.com

Answer (score 1):

Use the Google Chrome app for iOS.

1. Browse to [Google Images](http://images.google.com)
2. Tap the menu button in the top right corner at the end of the address bar (looks like three horizontal bars stacked on top of each other).
3. Tap "Request desktop site". The page will refresh and you should see the normal Google Images site.
4. Tap the blue camera icon in the Google search bar, then upload your pic or paste your URL as necessary.

Hope this helps! This does NOT work in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the Google app to your iPad.
2. Click the search space where you type keywords in and above the keyboard on your screen you will see a camera icon.
3. Click the icon and then you can take a photo and search using it.

You can obviously also do typed words.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternate browser like Opera, go to the settings, delete the cookies and change the User Agent as "Desktop" instead of Mobile, then open images.google.com. You'll have the camera icon like on your desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend http://searchbyimages.com is a reverse image search engine. Search by image: Give it an image and it will tell you where the image appears on the web.

Answer (score -1):

Download the app Puffin Free and go to Google.ca, then go to images. The camera should be beside the microphone.

Answer (score -2):

You could use "Image Web Search" from the App Store. [Here's a link to it.](https://appsto.re/us/RtFh6.i)

Comment: It seems that you are the developer of the app you've recommended. On this website, it is required that you disclose any affiliation with products or services.